# How to determine if an NSString is latin based?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to determine if a string is latin based or Japanese.

I've tried something like the following but it returns YES for Japanese strings as well:

```
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
BOOL isAlpha = [[myStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet] isEqualToString:@""];
```

A string might be a word like "café" or something like "カフェ" or "喫茶店".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [canBeConvertedToEncoding:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-canBeConvertedToEncoding_) method.  For example:

```
BOOL isLatin = [myString canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Available encodings are [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings).