# How to check a string is a number or letter

Tags: ios, string

I want to check a string is a number or letter in ios. eg "1"  or "error" can anybody tell me how to do this

Thanks

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671605/how-to-check-if-a-string-only-contains-alphanumeric-characters-in-objective-c

Comment: [refer this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only) you will find your answer. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSScanner:

```
NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];

if (![scan scanFloat:NULL] || ![scan isAtEnd])
{
     NSlog (@"%@", @"Is a string");
}
else
{
   NSlog (@"%@", @"Is a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL valid;
NSCharacterSet *alphaNums = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *inStringSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:String];
valid = [alphaNums isSupersetOfSet:inStringSet];    
if (!valid) // Not numeric
```